# How can I filter and list the last revision of a document if the Revision number is a string with letters (with formulas)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of more than 7 thousand of documents with different revisions. The revision letter is as follows (R00,R01...):

[image]

If I use this formula: =+IF(E3=MAX(IF($B$3:$B$7843=B3; $E$3:$E$7843));"Y";"N")

I can do it with numbers. But I would like to learn how to do it with a string, because I will find another examples where the revision could not be converted to numbers.

[image: Table with the formula]

What formula could I use for extracting the current revision of a string R00, R01, R02..?

Answer (score 0):

One way is:
if the revision in the next row is R00 or blank then this row is the last revision.

in D3 =IF(or(C4="R00",C4=""),"Y","N") and copy this formula down

Or if the next document ID is not the same as this document ID

=IF(B4<>B3,"Y","N")

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(COUNTIFS(C$3:C$7843,">="&C3,B$3:B$7843,B1)=1,"Y","N")`
This would also work if data is not in order.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I think that this is the best choice without having to convert the cell format to number. Very helpful!